# How to update the existing excel sheet with data frame in python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel sheet which has column A to H and all column has data excluding column D. Column D is empty I need to upend Column D with the data frame without deleting the existing  column data. please help me with this. Data frame look like below.

```
print(df)
```

> 101
>   201
>   301
>   401
>   501

excel is as shown below [image]

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you with any problems you have trying to solve a problem yourself - please try to solve the problem and if you have any problems, share your code, explain what the problem is and you're likely to get good help.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have below data.

```
Calendar Begin,Calendar End,Contract Start,NUM,Geo,PRODUCT,Sub PRODUCT
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
2017,2017 Q 4,1/1/2012 0:00,,AA,CCC,NAM
```

You can fill NUM column with below code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_src = pd.read_csv("src.csv")
# print(df_src)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    101,
    201,
    301,
    401,
    501,
])
# print(df)

df_src["NUM"] = df
# print(df_src)

# df_src:
#    Calendar Begin Calendar End Contract Start    NUM Geo PRODUCT Sub PRODUCT
# 0            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00  101.0  AA     CCC         NAM
# 1            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00  201.0  AA     CCC         NAM
# 2            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00  301.0  AA     CCC         NAM
# 3            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00  401.0  AA     CCC         NAM
# 4            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00  501.0  AA     CCC         NAM
# 5            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00    NaN  AA     CCC         NAM
# 6            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00    NaN  AA     CCC         NAM
# 7            2017     2017 Q 4  1/1/2012 0:00    NaN  AA     CCC         NAM

df_src.to_csv("out.csv")
```

Comment: this is a excel file not csv. i cannot use read_csv. When i use excel writer the existing  data is deleting